# Reference for the following cancellation theorems

Tags: reference-request, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

I found these two cancellation theorems in the K-book, in section 1.4, page 39:

> **Real Cancellation Theorem**: Suppose $X$ is a $d$-dimensional CW complex and $\eta:E\to X$ is an $n$-dimensional real vector bundle with $n > d$, then: 
> (i) $E\cong E_0\oplus T^{n-d}$ for some $d$-dimensional vector bundle $E_0$. 
> (ii) If $F$ is another bundle and $E\oplus T^k\cong F\oplus T^k$, then $E\cong F$.

> **Complex Cancellation Theorem**: Suppose $X$ is a $d$-dimensional CW complex and that $\eta:E\to X$ is a complex vector bundle with $\dim(E)\ge \frac{d}{2}$, then: 
> (i) $E\cong E_0\oplus T^k$ for some vector bundle $E_0$ of dimension $\le \frac{d}{2}$. 
> (ii) If $F$ is another bundle and $E\oplus T^k\cong F\oplus T^k$, then $E\cong F$.

I am interested in understanding the subtlety that appeared in the statements of these theorems: it seems like the complex case is analogous to the real case with half of the dimension since $\mathbb C\cong \mathbb R^2$, but the dimensions we get to pick are somewhat different. I tried to look up the reference in the K-book, which is Husemoller's *Fibre Bundles*, but I did not find what I want. Can anyone provide a reference or give an explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two theorems follow from obstruction theory, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/425262/21564) for example. Let me address why the inequalities are different in the real and complex cases. I will instead denote the real/complex dimension of the fibers of a vector bundle $E$ by $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{R}}E$ and $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{C}}E$ respectively.

As discussed in the linked answer, if the rank of $E$ (as a real vector bundle) is greater than the dimension of $X$, then $E \to X$ admits a nowhere-zero section $s$. This spans a one-dimensional trivial subbundle of $E$ (just as a non-zero vector in a real vector space spans a one-dimensional subspace isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$), so $E \cong E_0\oplus T$ where $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{R}} E_0 = \operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{R}} E - 1$ and $T$ is the trivial real line bundle. Provided $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{R}}E_0 > d$, we can repeat the same argument - this yields (i) in the real cancellation theorem.

Suppose now that $E$ is a complex vector bundle. Since $E$ is also a real vector bundle, we still have a nowhere-zero section $s$. Now however, it spans a one-dimensional trivial *complex* subbundle of $E$ (just as a non-zero vector in a complex vector space spans a one-dimensional subspace isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$), so $E \cong E_0\oplus T_{\mathbb{C}}$ where $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{C}}E_0 = \operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{C}}E - 1$ and $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the trivial complex line bundle. Provided $\operatorname{rank}_{\color{red}{\mathbb{R}}}E_0 > d$, we can repeat the same argument. Since $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{R}}E_0 = 2\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{C}}E_0$, the requirement $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{R}}E_0 > d$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{C}}E_0 > \frac{d}{2}$. This yields (i) in the complex cancellation theorem.